# javascript when using multiple if conditions get the failure reason

Tags: javascript

Over the years there have been multiple answers to this question, evolving from some clunky code.

In 2022 is there a one liner or improved way to get the condition that failed in a multiple `if` scenario?

example one,  `myVarTwo` fails

```
if (( myVarOne == "alpha") && ( myVarTwo == "beta") &&  ( myVarThree == "cappa"){
 // do stuff
 }else{
  console.log("failed at ...)
 }
```

example two,  `myVarThree` fails

```
if (( myVarOne == "alpha") && (( myVarTwo == "beta") ||  ( myVarThree == "cappa")){
 // do stuff
 }else{
  console.log("failed at ...)
 }
```

I am assuming the conditions test stops at the first fail.

Comment: edited based on comment from @AmehPls as original example 2 would pass on myVarOne

Comment: The edit itself is invalid, the condition will still resolve to `true` if `myVarThree` fails

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your assumption that the condition test stops at the first fail is correct. The logical `&&` operator is a [short-circuit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation) operator. It will return at the first instance of a falsy evaluation. Conversely, the `||` opearator returns at the first instance of a truthy evaluation.

With that said, my only guess would be to use ternary operators but I'm not sure if you would consider it to be a one liner. Especially if you have a lot more conditions to check for, the ternary operator would get really really long and not very readable. The ternary operators can be seen as simulating multiple `if...else` conditions being tested [sequentially](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#if...else_statement), with an action for each check.

```js
const myVarOne = "alpha",
  myVarTwo = "notBeta",
  myVarThree = "cappa"

const printFailure = (string) => {
  console.log(`Failed at ${string}`)
}

const printSuccess = () => {
  console.log('All conditions satisfied!')
}

// Method 1
myVarOne != "alpha" ? printFailure("myVarOne") : myVarTwo != "beta" ? printFailure("myVarTwo") : myVarThree != "cappa" ? printFailure("myVarThree") : printSuccess()

// Method 2
myVarOne == "alpha" ? myVarTwo == "beta" ? myVarThree == "cappa" ? printSuccess() : printFailure("myVarThree") : printFailure("myVarTwo") : printFailure("myVarOne")
```

Comment: @Madbreaks Yes, that would be another flaw to this method. In my opinion, if the _one-liner_ answer wasn't a requirement, the best option/practice would do a sequential if, elseif and else checks and perform the actions within each block.

Comment: agree, not a big improvement over the last 5 years. I was looking for example, a number  being returned in an err, that the check failed on, ie 0,1,2 based on what number actually triggered the fail